# How to print all columns in filtered condition for column using awk?

Tags: awk

I have comma separated file and i need to filter the file based upon some columns values; i am using following command which is giving me required result but i am unable to print all columns using following command.

The following command is giving me all columns avoiding filter; so the target file is same as size as source.

This is the command i am using

```
awk 'BEGIN{  FS=OFS=","}{  if($7=="\"3YM62AE#UUS\"" && $5=="\"01CS\""){    print $0  }}' file1.csv > file2.csv
```

[image]

Comment: `print $0` should print whole line, if you could show us your samples of input and expected output then we may get better picture of your requirement here. So please add sample of input and expected output and let us know then.

Comment: hi Ravinder i added the image file of sample data

Comment: @AniruddhaShinde, avoid adding image. Add source text.

Comment: @AniruddhaShinde, Kindly do edit your question and add samples in form of text which will provide us clear picture of your question.

Answer (score 0):

in your `awk` script ignore double quotes. Try something like:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS=","} $7=="3YM62AE#UUS" && $5=="01CS" { print }' file1.csv > file2.csv
```